# Grails project BuildConfig.groovy Tomcat plugin version?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm pretty new to grails and was wondering if the Tomcat plugin version has any effect if I were to WAR the project and deploy on an apache tomcat server?

For example, with grails 2.5.6 I have the tomcat plugin at 7.0.55 and after packaging it I deploy it on a apache server with Tomcat 7.0.100.

Or is it better to just go ahead upgrade the plugin version? I haven't been able to find a list of compatible versions with grails 2.5.6 if that is a thing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm pretty new to grails and was wondering if the Tomcat plugin
>   version has any effect if I were to WAR the project and deploy on an
>   apache tomcat server?

It does not.